# most efficient way to convert a number into a fraction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, fractions

supposing I have a decimal like 
  $$ 0.30000000000000027$$

What would be the best way to know the same number but in a fraction way like we know 
$\dfrac{1}{3} >  0.30 > \dfrac{1}{4}$

because I think there must be an algorithm given certain $x$ find  $y$ that satisfies  $x=\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: $$0.30000000000000027 = \frac{30000000000000027}{10^{17}}$$

Comment: is there a way to express that number as eqivalent to $1/y$ ? not doing $x*(length of y)$ / $length of y$ ?

Comment: In general given a certain $x$ there won't always be an integer $y$ such that $x= \frac{1}{y}$. Think of the number $.4 = \frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: yes I understand that but how to get to that number if it exists?

Comment: I wrote up a solution for you.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: yes thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an $x$ such that $x$'s decimal expansion goes like: 
$$
x=0.a_1a_2\ldots a_n
$$
Where $a_1a_2\ldots a_n$ are digits base $10$. 
Then $x$ is the rational number:
$$
x= \frac{a_1a_2\ldots a_n}{10^n} 
$$
If $x$ has the form
$$
x = \frac{1}{y} \;\;\; \text{for $y$ an integer}
$$
Then 
$$
y = \frac{10^n}{a_1a_2\ldots a_n} \;\;\; \text{and is an integer} 
$$
Yielding: 
$$
x=\frac{1}{\frac{10^n}{a_1a_2\ldots a_n}}
$$ 
 If $x$ doesn't have the form $\frac{1}{y}$, use euclid's algorithm  to compute the GCD of the numerator and the denominator, and then divide the numerator and the denominator by the GCD to put the fraction in lowest terms.

Comment: but is there a way to Compute the greatest common divisor for x and y then Divide both of them by the GCD to reduce the fraction or make it simplier? using Euclid's algorithm to compute the GCD.

Comment: @cMinor if $x$ has the form $\frac{1}{y}$ then the greatest common divisor *is* the numberator. ($a_1a_2\ldots a_n$). If $x$ doesn't have the form $\frac{1}{y}$, use euclid's algorithm  to compute the GCD(numberator,denominator).

Answer (score 1):

$$x= 0.30000000000000027$$

$$\implies 10^{17} \cdot x=30000000000000027$$

$$\implies x= \dfrac{30000000000000027}{10^{17}}$$